# Chrome extension on text changed event on text field, then replace text

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome Extension which I want to replace certain characters in a specific text field on one specific website. It is basically to change emoticon text (like ":-D") into the proper emoji's, such as "". I tried a few things I found online (I'm not very good with JS):
- A MutationObserver and then look for all text fields with a certain name, then replace all emoticons by hand. Didn't really do the job properly and also kept firing up the print window for some reason
- Event listener added with event 'keyup' but it doesn't seem to fire up.

Hope you guys know a good solution!

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean?

Comment: Can `html` , `js` tried be included at Question ?

Comment: I truly have no clue what you mean. Should I add it to the title of the question, or the tags maybe? Or are you asking if I can use them in a Chrome Extension project?

Comment: `html`: `html` described at Question ; i.e., element containing _"text field "_ ; `js`: `js` described at Question ; i.e., _"tried a few things I found online"_ . Can both `html` , `js` be included at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

This question does not give anywhere near enough information to answer. Are you using the program for input fields on the website? What solutions have you tried? Where is the code? Essentially, you are asking us to write the entire program for you. This forum is meant for programming help, NOT doing the entire program for you. You need to fix the question to be more specific.

If you just want to replace text elements, you would have to use the select elements by tag name to select all text elements on the page and then search through each of these for the sets of emoticons. Once finding these, you would have to change the elements inner html to fit the emoticon from UTF-8.

Comment: Hi Mikey. Sorry for the late response, had to attend a family day. I don't have much useful code yet, here it is so far: http://pastebin.com/cPxabAk2. I tried the solutions I already wrote in the main post without success (as you can see in the pastebin). Does this make it more clear? Sorry for initially being unclear.

Comment: Mikey do you perhaps know an answer to my question? I really don't know what to do.

Comment: So, if I am correct, you are wanting to edit input fields to change text such as :) to the happy face emoticon. I will start working on one at http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey013/hu7pnr88/

Comment: I assume that link means it will soon contain code when you publish it for testing? Anyway, sounds great man, looking forward to your idea's!

Comment: Should I see anything in that jsfiddle?

Comment: My mistake. I forgot the revision number. Give me one second to fix that.

Comment: Too late to edit. Try  jsfiddle.net/Mikey013/hu7pnr88/2